# How to manage ruby gems in linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, rvm

As I have started using Linux (Ubuntu) to broaden my knowledge, but the flow for ruby (rails) development does not feel so smooth as on Mac OSX.

Do you use rvm to manage ruby gems in Linux?

One particular issue I face is that I could install rails with only sudo command. But this forces me to use sudo for all the time under my rails project.

P.S.
Might be I am missing some point with the way you do things in Linux so it is not related to ruby (or rails) at all.

Comment: `>...But this forces me to use sudo for all the time under my rails project.` That is usually not the case. So either you did something wrong, or your flavor of Linux did. Once installed with sudo, "rails" command is available to all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is preferred to use `rvm`. we can install ruby and rails without rvm as well, but we can have only one version at a time. You can find the instructions to install rvm from following link - [rvm installation](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/).

If you are the only person working on ruby rails, install in single user mode(doesn't need to go with sudo)

Comment: Only note instead of ~/.bash_profile I had to add ~/.bashrc top line:
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function

Answer (score 2):

Installing ruby and rails only using superuser privileges means you're installing it from distribution packages. That's not recommended, and you get unneeded overload writting `sudo` before any rails command.

Install rvm or rbenv in your home directory and things should be smooth.